# ASP.Net web app running locally with IIS Server not running on Azure

Tags: asp.net, websocket, azure-web-app-service

I have simple ASP.Net web app in which there is **Socket connection** implementation.
It is working in local IIS Server, but not working when deployed on Azure.

Source Code on [GitHub](https://github.com/NiravMadariya/ASP.Net-WebSocket).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is working in local IIS Server, but not working when deployed on Azure.

I previously followed this [tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/youssefm/2012/07/17/building-real-time-web-apps-with-asp-net-webapi-and-websockets/) to build my web application with WebSockets. Per my understanding, you need to enable the **Web sockets** option under the "SETTINGS > Application settings" of your Azure web App on Azure Portal. Moreover, here is a similar tutorial about [Introduction to WebSockets on Windows Azure Web Sites](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites/), you could refer to it.

**UPDATE:**

For using SSL for WebSockets under Azure Web Apps, you could just connect to `wss://{your-appname}.azurewebsites.net (WebSockets over HTTPS).` Azure Web Sites supports SSL even on free sites by using a default SSL certificate for `*.azurewebsites.net`. Details you could follow this [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites/).

**TEST:**

[image]

Additionally, if it does not work in your web app, you could leverage the **Log stream** under the MONITORING section of your app service on Azure Portal to retrieve the detailed error message to narrow this issue.

Comment: Now, that I've made some changes, I also got it working it on Azure, but under `http://`, it's still not working with `https://`.

Comment: I updated my answer about using SSL for WebSockets under web app, you could refer to it.